# Get ImageView and TextView from RelativeLayout on clicking it

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am having ImageView and textview in Realtive Layout. Onclcik of Relative Layout i need to get the value of text View and need to change the imageview. Getting Null Pointer exception.
Here is the Code

activity Code

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                int id=0;

                    for (int idx = 0; idx < dataFromDb.size(); idx++) {
                        id = idx + 1;
                        rel = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
                                R.layout.newdata, null);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        params.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);
                        txt = (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.fetchData);
                        txt.setText(dataFromDb.get(idx));
                        txt.setId(id);

                        img = (ImageView) rel.findViewById(R.id.tickbox);
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tickbox1a);
                        img.setId(id);

                        rel.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Toast.makeText(DoTask.this,
                                        "Selected" + v.getId(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                RelativeLayout im=(RelativeLayout)v;
                                ImageView i=(ImageView)im.findViewById(im);
                                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.tickbox1b);
                            }
                        });

                        content.addView(rel, params);

                    }
```

newData.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tickbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/tickbox1a"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fetchData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Getting exception in onclick method

Comment: Why do you add many layout with loop from your database ? I think you should try to use `ListView`. And your `OnClick`, i think it should be `new OnClickListener`(from `android.view.View.OnClickListener` not `Dialog.OnClickListener`

) not `new ImageView.OnClickListener()`

Answer (score 5):

I believe you it should be like this:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(DoTask.this,
                                    "Selected" + v.getId(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            RelativeLayout im=(RelativeLayout)v;
                            ImageView i=(ImageView)im.findViewById(R.id.tickbox);
                            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.tickbox1b);
                        }
```

you are trying to call findViewById on relativelayout, wich is a view when it expects and id. 
Or just use the img you defined above, there is no need to create another instance of imageview because you already have one.

Answer (score 0):

Activity code should be

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            int id=0;

                for (int idx = 0; idx < dataFromDb.size(); idx++) {
                    id = idx + 1;
                    rel = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.newdata, null);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);
                    txt = (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.fetchData);
                    txt.setText(dataFromDb.get(idx));
                    txt.setId(id);

                    img = (ImageView) rel.findViewById(R.id.tickbox);
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tickbox1a);
                    img.setId(id);

                    rel.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(DoTask.this,
                                    "Selected" + v.getId(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tickbox1b);
                        }
                    });

                    content.addView(rel, params);

                }
```

Comment: I need to get the value of textView. how can i get so ?

Comment: String input = txt.getText().toString();
Now input has your required value as String